# Geospark: Is it possible to input the data from HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, geospatial

As mentioned in the below link, Geospark takes the data in CSV or Tab delimited format. We can take the data from HDFS, convert it into CSV and pass it to Geospark for processing.

Can we directly use Geospark on HDFS and do the processing?

https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark

> GeoSpark supports either Comma-Separated Values (CSV) or Tab-separated
>   values (TSV) as the input format. Users only need to specify input
>   format as Splitter and the start column of spatial info in one tuple
>   as Offset when call Constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use GeoSpark to do it. GeoSpark supports the same data sources as Apache Spark. In terms of format, GeoSpark supports CSV, TSV, WKT and GeoJSON.